# Hibernate: Update parent in Many to One relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

Trying to update Parent while updating the child in a many-one relationship. Here is the `hbm.xml`

```
<class name="childProduct" table="CHILD_PRODUCT" lazy="true">
  <many-to-one name="parent" class="Parent" column="Parent_ID" lazy="false" update="true"/>
</class>
```

**Parent.java**

```
String att1;
String att2;
String att3;

//Getter and Setters are there
```

Here what I do in the Dao class:

```
//Read the entity
entity = dao.read(request.getId());
//Set the entity from request
entity.setSomeAttribute(request.getSomeAttribute());
entity.setParent(request.getParent());
```

In this way if I am not sending any of the attribute value in request, it gets set as null for Parent. But it does not happen for childProduct.

How would I make sure that only the values sent from request, gets updated?

Comment: You can use `annotations`, to avoid xml-mapping.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, or what your code does. What does not happen for the childProduct? Only the values that you set on your entity will be updated, the ones you did not touch will not.